# How to select specific tags from Mule API html response using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xml, mule, fetch, dom-manipulation

I have a *Mule app* that returns an **html document** as text, the document contains `<tr/>` and `<td/>` tags that have the information I am trying to access.  How to select specific tags from Mule API *html response*?

```javascript
async function getTag(env, val) {
    try {
        let hashes = await fetch(`/admin/api/html/ref/${env}/${val}`)
            .then(res => { return (res.text()) })
            .then(data => {
                let count = 0
                console.log(data)
            })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, ***not a tutorial site or help/discussion forum***.  You have neglected to ask a question.  What is the problem you are having?
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) to learn how to use this site effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to parse the html text returned by an API call and retrieve some info from it?

If yes, you need to use the DOMParser object to parse the html response and then process it the way you like.

Here is an example

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, 'text/html');
 // do whatever you want with htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName or using htmlDoc.querySelector
```

In your case you want all the `<td>` so you do something like

```
// use any selector you would like
var info = htmlDoc.querySelectorAll("tr");
```

Reference:
[DOMParser - Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)